# Playing video on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, slider

```
<div class="video-grid-one">
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
</div>


<div class="video-grid-two">
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
</div>

<div class="button"> Video one </div>
<div class="button"> Video two </div>

.button {
    height:45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Hey guys I'm creating a slider with thumbnail. And there is some customization in it. Sometimes when we hover on a carousel image the slider should automatically play a video related to that image which we hover. Here I have attached something above, when we hover on a button the video should play automatically. Can you guys help me with that? Thanks :)

No possibilities for that?

Comment: You better go through some jquery. Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23284050/8273382

Comment: Hey  Thanks  Dumindu De Silva, but I'm looking for something better..:)

Comment: When I hover on that button the video should play. When I remove mouse from that button it should stop playing. Also when again I hover on that button THE VIDEO SHOULD START PLAYING FROM THE BEGINNING.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video id="video-one" width="400" controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

add id to your video tag and include jquery in your html file
add script and also add id to your button div

```
<div class="button" id="hover-one"> Video one </div>

<script>
$("#hover-one").hover(function(){
    $("#video-one")[0].play();
});
</script>
```

now add this script and it will play video on hover of button div

Comment: Hey Asad, this is awesome. Can we do one more thing?  
When I hover on that button the video should play. When I remove mouse from that button it should stop playing. Also when again I hover on that button THE VIDEO SHOULD START PLAYING FROM THE BEGINNING. Can we do this? I'm completely new this field that's why I keep asking :)

Comment: yes we can i will create a fiddle for that and share you the link of that fiddle

Comment: Thanks Asad. That will help me a lot :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ey4fmu03/2/
here i have created a demo for you i have used video js for doing  play pause the video hope you got your answer "https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.4/video.js" this is the link for video js. if you face any difficulty please feel free to contact

Comment: Sure:) can you provide your personal email ID?

Comment: yup sure webdev.asad@gmail.com